# Finding solutions for $2^n+21\equiv0\pmod n$ and $2^n+39\equiv0\pmod n$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In recent days, I have been studying the equation $m^n+h \equiv 0 \pmod n$ where $m,n \in \mathbb N$ and $h\in\mathbb Z $, and I have recently commenced a search for m=2 and h=11, which a solution is found after a brute force search for all numbers $\leq 20000000000$ at $n=16043199041$. At the course of my research, I have also noticed that for $m=2$, $h=21$ and $h=39$ have no solutions $\leq 1000000000$ except the trivial solutions($n=1,23$ for $h=21$ and $n=1,41$ for $h=39$). How can I find the desired solutions to the equalities?

Comment: 18 =0  (mod n) hope you

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi I'm asking for solutions for the 2 separate equalities, not solutions that simultaneously satisfy both of them.

Comment: oh sorry ik heb het verkeerd begrepen

Comment: You've recently asked [a very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3820545/318073).

Answer (score 2):

After factoring $2^k+21$ and $2^k+39$ for $k$ that are possible prime factors of $n$ for $n|2^n+21$ and $n|2^n+39$ respectively, I have found separate non-trivial solutions that satisfies the equalities.

For $n|2^n+21$, $n=2084635635376741=53 \times 39332747837297$ (found by factoring $2^{53}+21$)

For $n|2^n+39$, $n=239619112311215716196617852691883322466420613359991721524173703248933=239 \times 1002590428080400486178317375279846537516404239999965362025831394347$ (found by factoring $2^{239}+39$)

Now, the following question remains: Does the equation $2^n+k\equiv0\pmod n$ always have non-trivial solutions? A discussion is made in [Existence of non-trivial solution $n$ for all odd integers $k$ such that $n\mid 2^n+k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3822420/existence-of-non-trivial-solution-n-for-all-odd-integers-k-such-that-n-mid/).