# Existence of non-trivial solution $n$ for all odd integers $k$ such that $n\mid 2^n+k$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

[Note: $a\mid b$ means '$a$ divides $b$' in the following context.]

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ be a solution to $n\mid 2^n+k$, where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ is an arbitrary odd integer.

Besides $n=1$, which is a solution for all $k$, Fermat's little theorem states that the prime factors of $|2+k|$ are also solutions. Define these solutions as *trivial*. Hereafter, let $n$ denote a non-trivial solution.

For example, in the case of $k=-11$, the solutions $1$ and $3$ (as the prime factor of $|2-11| = 9$) are considered trivial.  The first non-trivial solution is $n=262279$, as per [the sequences shown in OEIS](http://oeis.org/wiki/2%5En_mod_n).

Another example is the recent discovery in [StrongestStrike's post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820545/how-do-i-find-solutions-to-2n11-equiv-0-pmod-n) that the first non-trivial solution for $k=11$ is $n=16043199041$. In fact, it was [Max Alekseyev](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/147470/max-alekseyev) (the author of most of the above OEIS sequences) who found the solution after using a method that can be found on [Joe K. Crump's page](https://web.archive.org/web/20120104074313/http://www.immortaltheory.com/NumberTheory/2nmodn.htm) in the *Some Theory* and *Patterns* section. In this case, $2^{347}+11$ has a **suitable** prime factor $46234003$ and hence $347 \times 46234003 = 16043199041$ was found. This does not work for most other prime factors.

[Derek Orr](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/169588/derek-orr), another contributor to the OEIS sequences, pointed out that $21$ and $39$ are two examples of other values of $k$ with no $n$ found so far. With this in mind, I would like to ask: can a non-trivial solution be found for every odd integer except $-1$? Formally, if we define $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ as an arbitrary odd integer except $k=-1$, does the following stand? $$\forall k\, \exists\, n(2^n \equiv -k\pmod n)$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I would like to express my heartfelt gratitude to Max Alekseyev and Derek Orr for their kind assistance. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After factoring $2^k+21$ and $2^k+39$ for $k$ that are possible prime factors of $n$ for $n|2^n+21$ and $n|2^n+39$ respectively, I have found separate non-trivial solutions that satisfies the equalities.

For $n|2^n+21$, $n=2084635635376741=53 \times 39332747837297$ (found by factoring $2^{53}+21$)

For $n|2^n+39$, $n=239619112311215716196617852691883322466420613359991721524173703248933=239 \times 1002590428080400486178317375279846537516404239999965362025831394347$ (found by factoring $2^{239}+39$)

Comment: There are infinitely many odd integers and it seems unlikely to me that a counterexample will be found simply by exhausting every $k$ (which is also very slow). A general proof would be more desirable but thanks for your efforts!